# State of Javascript Global Variable binding Inside a function

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables, scope

I am carrying out an AJAX call (with dojo) and I wanted to know what's the best way to have to pass the calling object to the callback function

```
var that = this;
dojo.xhrGet({
    url : 'script.php',
    handleAs : "javascript",
    load : function(response){
        /*The callback on success*/
        console.log('Ajax Completed Successfully for: ' + that.name);
    }
});
```

My question is whether `load` is created at 'compile time', or whether it is evaluated at 'run time'. Basically, if the value of `that` changes between when it is created `var that = this` and when it is called after AJAX returns and calls `load`, will this change be reflected in `load`? If so, then what's the best practice for ensuring the AJAX return signal calls the correct object? Do I have to create a specific load function for every object?

Thanks

Comment: In JavaScript there is no such thing as **compile time**, it is **run time** !!!

Comment: That is why I put them in quotes. Most scripting languages actually do not compile, they interpret. I'm assuming it's the same case ehre

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enclose your load inside a `closure`:

```
(function(that){
    dojo.xhrGet({
        url : 'script.php',
        handleAs : "javascript",
        load : function(response){
            /*The callback on success*/
            console.log('Ajax Completed Successfully for: ' + that.name);
        }
    });
})(this);
```

The `(function(x){ })(x);` part is a self executing function which gives the value of `x` or `this` as an argument to the self executing function. The value `x` or `that` remains what it should be.

Comment: Awesome! I knew there was a use for `(function(x){ })(x);` other than to look like you were a veteran JS coder.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do, you can avoid having to create with the `load:` at all by using deferreds:

```
function get_data(){
    return dojo.xhrGet({
        url : 'script.php',
        handleAs : "javascript",
    });
}

function other_function(){
    var that = this;
    get_data().then(function(response){
        console.log("Ajax completed for" + that.name);
    });
}
```

(I don't remember if this also works when the ajax fails - need to test this bit)

Comment: I like betamax's answer better because it is easier to read and does not split the Ajax call apart. Thanks for educating me on the `then` statement though